# Why is $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] showing a wrong ip?

Tags: php, ip

I'm using `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];` to get the IP of the visitors. I don't care if they are behind a proxy, VPN, etc; I need a measure of IP that can't be manipulated by the end-user.

For some users, `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];` is not returning the right IP -- it is returning one of Google's IPs instead, such as `64.233.173.164`.

I confirmed this by asking one user to check their IP by checking [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=what%20is%20my%20ip%20address&rct=j) and their IP turned out to be different than what `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];` showed.

How is that possible?

UPDATE: I've talked to the specific user in question and he said he is NOT using Google Translate. Why else would a Google IP show in REMOTE_ADDR?

Comment: may be they translate your page

Comment: Are you sure it is you user's IP. It may be one of google robots or something like that?

Comment: "I just need a measure of IP that can't be manipulated by the end-user." i can change my IP, im an end user. IP can never be used to reliably identify any one. hundreds of people can share a single IP

Comment: @FastSnail Ahhhh could be. Is it possible for me to detect IP past their translate pge?

Comment: @MikaA. It was not a Google robot. I know for sure it was a user.

Comment: @Dagon I don't care if you use a VPN or proxy.

Comment: @user4951834 if you know the user ask them did they use google translater

Comment: do you care if every page request i make uses a different IP? or if 100 visitors use a single IP?

Comment: @FastSnail On it. Is there any way for me to detect when a user uses Google Translate and somehow get their real IP instead of Google's?

Comment: @user4951834 i don't think you can get real ip if they use google translater or something like that .howevery you could detect it's coming from google

Comment: google translator is effectively a proxy in this case, which you dont care about - not that i'm sure what you do care about.

Comment: @FastSnail Anyway to detect it is coming from Google aside from manually collecting their IPs and keeping track of them?

Comment: @Dagon I care about allowing one transaction per IP. However, when people use Google translate, many people end up sharing the same IPs. I'm not concerned about other proxies / VPNs because people who use those proxies and VPNs know they are behind a proxy and VPN and turn it off when we tell them their IP has been used. Same isn't true for Google Translate users.

Comment: @user4951834 can you clarify it for me .i don't get it

Comment: @FastSnail I mean, I want to be able to display a message to people using Google Translate. Any way for me to detect when a user is using Google Translate?

Comment: one transaction per IP = for reasons i pointed out before this can never work.

Comment: @user4951834 read this [so question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27665531/how-to-find-googles-ip-address) .and also search for google ip range

Comment: @Dagon Please, just stop. I'm well aware of what I'm doing when I'm tracking IPs and why. I asked about why REMOTE_ADDR is showing what it is, not advice on why I shouldn't use REMOTE_ADDR. If you can't provide constructive help, stop trolling.

Comment: @FastSnail Thank you. I will look into this. I will also look into javascript to detect Google Translate.

Comment: @FastSnail Also, FYI, user says he wasn't using Google Translate when we detected the above-mentioned Google IP

Comment: @user4951834 i'm not sure why .my guesses are google se bots or translater or googles services .but if they don't use any of those i don't know .

Comment: im actually trying to help your just to stubborn to realize\understand it

Comment: Did you try this answer yet? http://stackoverflow.com/a/55790/1570534

Comment: @FastSnail I know, this is very weird. I'm going to try and get more information out of the user. This isn't the only user this is happening to, though -- I am seeing a good number of Google IPs in our system.

Comment: @HankyPanky I cannot use the other options aside from REMOTE_ADDR because I don't want the user manipulating their IPs (outside of using proxy, VPN, etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I don't care if they are behind a proxy, VPN, etc;

You have to, if they are using a VPN, or a proxy, or NAT then `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` will contain **that** ip and not of the user, and that is what you're getting.

> UPDATE: I've talked to the specific user in question and he said he is NOT using Google Translate. Why else would a Google IP show in REMOTE_ADDR?

That Google IP you have mentioned in your OP belongs to `google-proxy-64-233-173-164.google.com` which is the proxy that this visitor's computer or ISP is using

If you were to check `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` or `HTTP_CLIENT_IP` You would get that information

Comment: What exactly would the user be using to get a Google IP, aside from Google Translate which he said he is not using?

Comment: That Google IP you have mentioned in your OP belongs to `google-proxy-64-233-173-164.google.com` which is the proxy that this visitor's computer or ISP is using.

Comment: So the ISP is using Google proxy in the backend? How can I reliably get `HTTP_CLIENT_IP` without risking the user simply changing it at their end? As I said, I don't care if they use a VPN or proxy, but I don't want them just cycling through IPs by simply changing their headers.

Comment: Unless your users are technically aware of what they are trying to break and use a client software which allows them to change request headers, this is not a problem. Can you tell me how would you change your client ip using chrome/ff/ie when you visit my site? IP is not a reliable indicator of an exact client anyway even if you manage to perfect it

Comment: Fair enough. What is prefered, `HTTP_CLIENT_IP` or `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` ?

Comment: I usually check `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` and `REMOTE_ADDR` together